# Solve couple of differential equations using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, differential-equations

I have to solve this couple of differential equations

```
dxdt = a - b*x*z

dydt = c*y*exp(-E)

dzdt = dxdt - sum(dydt*dE)
```

with a, b and c constants and E an array.

As you can see, I need to process an integration over E to determine dzdt. Thus, dydt is an array also.

I don't know how to solve this kind of equations using Python because odeint requires the initial conditions as one-dimensional.

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You might want to look at [PyDSTool](https://pydstool.github.io/PyDSTool/FrontPage.html)

Comment: What is `E` a function of? Given a time `t` and the state vector for it, how do you actually extract the correct value from the array of `E` samples?

Comment: The usual trick is to introduce an additional component `w` so that `dwdt = dydt*dEdt` if it were known how to compute `dEdt`.

Comment: Or did you mean that `y` is an array or vector of the same dimension as `E`?

Comment: E is not a function of t. Thus I can't introduce an additional component.